# Состоится Таинство крещения или будет проводится Таинство крещения

Tags: стилистика

Недавно мне задали вопрос "Как правильно: состоится Таинство крещения или Будет проводится Таинство крещения"? Учитывая, что крещение - это  обряд, я сказал, что правильнее: "будет проводиться". Мое мнение подтвердила справка (Грамма.ру). Отмечу сразу, что это текст объявления.

Уважаемые прихожане! 
 Доводим до вашего сведения, что в воскресенье в 16:00 состоится (оригинал) / будет проводится Таинство крещения.

Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение, желательно с подтверждением авторитетных источников.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«*Совершение таинства св. Крещения сопровождается на Руси пиром (крестины), к которому приглашаются знакомые и родственники*» ([Энциклопедический словарь Ф.А. Брокгауза и И.А. Ефрона](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz_efron/56818/Крещение)).

«*Совершать таинства могут только посвященные от лица церкви*» ([Основы духовной культуры](http://spiritual_culture.academic.ru/2193/Таинство)).

Comment: Это и так ясно. Вопрос не этом. Вопрос в том, какой глагол употребить: будет проводится или состоится( в тексте объявления).

Comment: Употребить нужно глагол "совершится".

Comment: Ответ Грамота.ру: Возможны оба варианта. Разные специалисты - разные мнения. И все же, скорее всего, Вы правы. Лучше: будет совершаться.

Comment: Совсем хорошо: *будет совершено*.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно проводят  заранее запланированные мероприятия: репетицию, заседание, соревнование.  Об этих же мероприятиях можно сказать, что они состоялись или состоятся.

Таинство крещения  тоже планируется заранее, но  использование в этом случае глаголов «состояться, провести» придает  ему сниженный  и светский оттенок.

Таинство всегда соВЕРШается, и священник, проводящий обряд,  -  это лишь лицо, СОпричастное к  особой, ВЕРШинной духовности.

Comment: София, т.е. нужно сказать: будет совершаться? Да? Или же: будет совершенно?

Comment: Думаю, что могут употребляться обе формы, например: "В рамках визита Патриарх совершил таинство крещения в новой православной церкви святого Серафима". "Совершилось Таинство Церкви ― силой, благодатью, нашествием Святого Духа, верой народной, молитвами Церкви".